# Lock the Height resizing in a .NET Custom Control while in design mode

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I'm developing a C# .NET Custom Control and I want to prevent the user, while in design mode, from resizing the Height, while allowing them to reize the Width.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this question is a little old, but just in case someone looks for this I'll try to answer it:

You have to override the [SetBoundsCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore.aspx) method in your user control. Something like this:

```
protected override void SetBoundsCore(
    int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
{
    // EDIT: ADD AN EXTRA HEIGHT VALIDATION TO AVOID INITIALIZATION PROBLEMS
    // BITWISE 'AND' OPERATION: IF ZERO THEN HEIGHT IS NOT INVOLVED IN THIS OPERATION
    if ((specified & BoundsSpecified.Height) == 0 || height == DEFAULT_CONTROL_HEIGHT)
    {
        base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, DEFAULT_CONTROL_HEIGHT, specified);
    }
    else
    {
        return; // RETURN WITHOUT DOING ANY RESIZING
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set `MinHeight` and `MaxHeight` properties?

Comment: Does not prevent shrinking the height--unless both are same.  Plus, this blocks it even in runtime mode.

Comment: There is no MinHeight & MaxHeight properties, only MinSize and MaxSize, and one has to set both the height and width proeprties for them to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the '[`DesignMode`](http://en.csharp-online.net/Design-Time_Integration%E2%80%94DesignMode_Property)' property, this indicates that you are in design mode, *i.e.* from the UI designer mode.  (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996457.aspx)).

```
public int Height()
{
    get { ... }
    set
    { 
        if (this.DesignMode) return;
        else this.myHeight = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has the odd effect of crashing Visual Studio but it appears to be on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Override SetBoundsCore method to set resize limits
```

//this code fixes the height to 20, and other attributes can be changed

```
      protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y,
   int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
        {
            // Set a fixed height for the control.
            base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, 20, specified);
        }
```