# What is the use of SetBoundsCore?

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't know the usage of the `SetBoundsCore` and if any sample program it is comfortable.
I have googled but didn't get one. Is it used for retain the same value?
For example, if set the `height` as `100` for first time it will remain the same and if i set the `height` as `200` it will not change again.
I assume like this.

```
protected override void SetBoundsCore(
    int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
{
   base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width,height, specified);
}
```

Comment: `SetBoundsCore` is called when you set the `Bounds` property of a Control, or when you call `SetBounds()`. It's the method that actually performs the change, taking care of a possible Layout of the parent container, triggered by  `SetWindowPos`.

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478675/lock-the-height-resizing-in-a-net-custom-control-while-in-design-mode

Comment: Sorry PaulF i didnt get this and thanks for the link you suggest.Thanks jimi for clarifying the doubt.

Comment: It is the parent of a control that sets the Size, like the form.  You can override SetBoundsCore to demand your own size.  TextBox is a good example, its Height is fixed by the size of the font.  So it overrides SetBoundsCore to defeat attempts at making it taller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between SetBounds and SetBoundsCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776864/what-is-the-difference-between-setbounds-and-setboundscore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_SetBoundsCore_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_BoundsSpecified_)

Basically it sets coordinates and size of your control. Since it is protected and virtual, you can only call it from your user control like you specified in your question.

Difference between `public` method `SetBounds()` and `SetBoundsCore()` is here:

[What is the difference between SetBounds and SetBoundsCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776864/what-is-the-difference-between-setbounds-and-setboundscore)